# Cannot get the lastest emitted value from the another component in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

Hi guys I am trying to get the latest updated value of a variable from component **app-confirm-bottom-sheet** in **app-bene-verification.ts** component but cannot get it.
Below is my code of component **app-confirm-bottom-sheet.ts**

```
import { FormControl, FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { ChangeDetectorRef, Component, Inject, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MatBottomSheet, MAT_BOTTOM_SHEET_DATA } from '@angular/material/bottom-sheet';
import { UtilityService } from '../../services/utility.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-confirm-bottom-sheet',
  templateUrl: './confirm-bottom-sheet.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./confirm-bottom-sheet.component.scss']
})
export class ConfirmBottomSheetComponent implements OnInit {

  sheetData: any;
  confirmForm!: FormGroup;
  npciUserName:any=''

  constructor(
    private bottomSheet: MatBottomSheet,
    @Inject(MAT_BOTTOM_SHEET_DATA) public data: any = {},
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    private changeDetector: ChangeDetectorRef,
    private utilityService: UtilityService
  ) {

  }
  ngOnInit(): void {

  }
  updateUserName(): void {
    this.utilityService.updateNpciUserName(this.npciUserName);
  }
  checkNpci() {
    console.log(this.npciUserName);
  }
```

Below is the HTML of **app-confirm-bottom-sheet.html**

```
      <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="npciUserName" placeholder="Enter your name" (keyup)="updateUserName()" >
```

Below is the code of **app-bene-verification.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormGroup, Validators, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';
import { MatPaginator, PageEvent } from '@angular/material/paginator';
import { MatSort } from '@angular/material/sort';
import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material/table';
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';
import { MatBottomSheet } from '@angular/material/bottom-sheet';
import { ConfirmBottomSheetComponent } from './../../../../common/dialogs/confirm-bottom-sheet/confirm-bottom-sheet.component';
import { BankValidationService } from '../../services/bank-validation.service';
import { UtilityService } from './../../../../common/services/utility.service';
import { ExportService } from './../../../../common/services/export.service';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';

export interface BeneData {
  agent_ref_id: string
  agent_mobile_no: string
  account_holder_name: string
  account_number: string
  ifsc_code: string
  bank_name: string
  account_validation_status_refid: string
  bank_id: number
  retailer_name: string
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-bene-verification',
  templateUrl: './bene-verification.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./bene-verification.component.scss']
})
export class BeneVerificationComponent implements OnInit {

  npciUserName: any = '';
  npciUserNameSubscription!: Subscription;
  constructor(private bankValidationService: BankValidationService,
    private datePipe: DatePipe,
    private bottomSheet: MatBottomSheet,
    public utilityService: UtilityService,
    private exportService: ExportService,
    private fb: FormBuilder
  ) {
    this.range = new FormGroup({
      fromDate: new FormControl(),
      toDate: new FormControl()
    });
    this.npciUserName = 'Default Value';
  }

  queryParams: any;
  nbtFormGroup!: FormGroup;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.npciUserNameSubscription = this.utilityService.npciUserName$.subscribe({
      next: (value: any) => {
        if (this.npciUserName === '' || this.npciUserName === null) {
          this.npciUserName = value;
        }
      },
      error: (error: any) => {
        console.error('Error fetching npciUserName:', error);
        this.npciUserName = 'Default Value'; // or handle the error in another way
      }
    });

   
    this.queryParams = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('queryParams') as any);
    this.fromDate.setValue(new Date());
    this.toDate.setValue(new Date());
    this.getBeneDetails(this.fromDate.value, this.toDate.value);
    this.getReasonsList()
  }
}
```

**npciUserName** is always set to Default value. The latest value of **npciUserName**  from **app-confirm-bottom-sheet.html** is not reflected in **app-bene-verification.ts**

Below is the code of the **utility-service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { MatSnackBar, MatSnackBarConfig } from '@angular/material/snack-bar';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UtilityService {

  constructor(private _snackBar: MatSnackBar) { }
  private npciUserNameSubject = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);
  npciUserName$ = this.npciUserNameSubject.asObservable();

  updateNpciUserName(value: any) {
    this.npciUserNameSubject.next(value);
  }
```

So How can get the latest emitted value of **npciUserName** from confirm-bottom-sheet in bene-verification.ts ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the `if` condition on the next block! Currently you will update the value only if it equals either `''` or `null` which is wrong, the new code will update it if its anything but `''` or `null`!

```
...
if (this.npciUserName !== '' && this.npciUserName !== null) { // <- changed here!
      this.npciUserName = value;
}
...
```